# Java - Problem with abstraction

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

I have this trouble. Im working with some library, and i need to create an istance of a class that is an interface.

- If i do `this.createITextArea()` it will create the object.
- If i do `ITextArea area = new ITextArea()` i can't, because the class is abstract.

In fact, i need to send it trought a function. But with first method i can't, or i don't know how to get the variable for that class. How can I pass it?

I need somethings like `area=this.createITextArea()`, so i can use the variable area in the function...

Hope the question is clear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what's the problem with this:

```
ITextArea area = this.createITextArea();
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Despite the question being a bit unclear:

E.g.:

```
ITextArea area = this.createITextArea();
someObj.someMeth(area);
```

or inline:

```
someObj.someMeth(this.createITextArea());
```

I'd recommend further reading on Java Interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

You do NOT need to create an instance of an interface. You need to create an instance of a class which *implements* said interface. Find or write such an implementation, instantiate that, and then assign it to your variable.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of a class is **never** an interface. A method may return an interface type, but the "thing", that you get through the method, is always an object which implements this interface.

Some simple examples to illustrate it:

```
public static main(String[] args) {
  List list = createList();
}

public static List createList() {
  return new ArrayList();
}
```

The `createList` method returns an interface type (`List`) **but** it returns an instance of a real class (`ArrayList`). So at the end, the local variable `list` holds a reference to this instance of `ArrayList`.

Back to your example: Assuming you have an interface

```
public interface ITextArea { /* methods */ }
```

and want to create an object "that implements this interface", then you need another class like

```
public class TextArea implements ITextArea { /* methods */ }
```

and you'll want to create instances of this concrete class.